# Do I have different python versions and which one I am working with?

Tags: python-3.x, installation

I am confused about different python versions on my Computer and in Anaconda.

First: I use an iMac (OSX Catalina).I sometimes use the command line (Terminal on my iMac) directly and sometimes I use Anaconda Navigator (for example when I want to work with Jupyter Notebooks).

When I type python3 --version, I get the answer that I have python 3.8.0 installed. But recently, I installed the latest pip version with pip3 --user --upgrade pip. The answer I got was:

WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.
pip 20.0.2 from /Users/Andrea_5K/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)

I wondered why in this message python 3.7 is referenced.

When I check my Library/Python folder in my user folder I see that I have a 3.7 folder and a 3.8 folder as well. Is there something wrong? Is pip 20.0.2 now installed on python 3.7 although I use python 3.8? And what does the WARNING message mean?

Comment: It looks like you have two version installed. The `pip` shebang line tells it to run python3.7. What it is suggesting is to always invoke it as a module with `-m` to avoid that problem. `python3.8 -m pip ...` should work.

Comment: `which pip` also `pip3 --version` which will tell you were it is loaded from.

Comment: Thanks @Keith: So do I have to uninstall one version? I have also installed Anaconda...does that mean that I have installed three versions of python on my computer? 3.7, 3.8 and the one within Anaconda?

Comment: Probably, I believe Anaconda has its own version installed. I know having anaconda installed and interfere with other Python installations. I usually have people uninstall that. 
But if you use the specific Python interpreter (python3.8) as show above, that should also work.